# Use a public directory from a different domain in ExpressJS 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

I am working on deploying a simple Express app to Heroku. It is basically a portfolio site that serves images in response to ajax calls from javascript on the client side. Right now all of my images (as well as other static css and client side JS files) are in the Public directory which is created when instantiating the app via the Express CLI generator.

Everything works fine when I run it locally, but I didn't want to upload my image files directly to Heroku. It seems easiest to have the app running there so that I don't have to deal with setting that server up myself, but I wanted to serve the images from hosting I pay for elsewhere. It seemed like it would be simple enough to serve all of my static files, just by changing where Express' middleware looked for the Public directory:

```
// Works like this with everything in one place:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// What I thought I could do to serve from elsewhere:
app.use(express.static('www.mydomain.net/path/to/public'));
```

I have tried a number of variations on this, like including __dirname (even though I am pretty sure that is wrong) and altering the paths (including adding / to the front of www.mydomain.net). I've also made sure that the paths elsewhere don't include './' on the front, so they shouldn't be looking in their own directories.

None of these work--I have tried them all locally using both foreman and npm start, as well as by actually pushing to my heroku master. I see the basic skeleton of the HTML, but the CSS and JS aren't applied and the image doesn't appear. The console shows 404 errors for everything.

I've googled pretty extensively and learned a fair amount about Express and Heroku, but still have not been able to make this work. So, is there a simple solution that I am overlooking, or am I trying to do something that just doesn't make sense?

EDIT: I couldn't figure this out so I just went ahead and installed the whole app on one server. Worked fine, though I am still curious about this.